# inserting html control values into sql server using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql, sql-server-2005

I want to insert the values into sql server and display into the form again.  I am having my controls in html only.

Since I am using more javascript, I can't change this to asp.net controls.  Now I want to insert html dropdown, text controls into Sql Server database.  After that, I want to display it into the form.

Comment: 27% acceptance rating doesn't motivate me to help...

Comment: You should insert the **data values** into SQL Server - **NOT** the entire HTML controls...

Comment: @govind : problem is i cant get the id of html controls in c#.if i give the html idand insert with htmlcontrolid.text ,c# showing that id is not in the current text

Comment: @marc:yes i have to insert data values only not the html controls..how to do that

Comment: That's your prerogative, but the community will frown on you until that changes.

Comment: You asked **26 questions** - and for **only 6 of those** you've received a useful solution??? Unlikely.....

Comment: @OMG:k thanks for your suggestion.I will accept the answers surely if it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

you cant send html tag's to server ...
to do this yo must changhe this attribute in your page Directive in html Source

```
AutoEventWireup="true"=====>AutoEventWireup="false"
```

then you can save your html string in sql

Comment: @Azad:Even if i change the autoeventwireup to false html controls ID is not recognized in c#

Answer (score 0):

i found as;

Html controls can be used in csharp as;

in the tag u should define runat attribue 
so that we can get the id's in c#

```
string a=erp.value;
```